# Line of best fit through data points

Tags: python, scikit-learn, best-fit-curve

[image: Image of data ponits]

Ideally want a polynomial fit or Gaussian Process Regression. Unsure how to implement this in sklearn. Data is stored in pandas.

I have tried the below, but it loads very slowly, even when there are only 128 data points.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X, y = df11[['P1FRAMES']], df11[['A']]
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(X, y).predict(X)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(X, y).predict(X)
```

Is there a faster way to generate a second order polynomial best-fit line? Or any other best-fit line that you think might be suitable?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: [This example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html) might help you - a scikit-learn example of plotting polynomial interpolation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have followed this and it works. Last question...how do I get the coefficients of each of the polynomials? Have tried using named_steps but can't see where to get them.

Comment: @TomDry Both regressors Ridge and SVR use `coef_` (weights) and `intercept_` internally.